# Invalid Arguments in (std::string).find and (std::string).replace

Tags: c++, eclipse, string, c++11, cocos2d-x

I am using the following code to replace a string within a string.

The same code as below is working in Visual Studio 2012 but not in Eclipse, and I can't figure out why. 
The error is about invalid arguments in the `find` and `replace` functions of `std::string`:

```
void ReplaceStringInPlace(std::string& subject, const std::string& search, const std::string& replace)
{
    // handle error situations/trivial cases
    if (search.length() == 0)
    {
        // searching for a match to the empty string will result in an infinite loop
        return;
    }
    if (subject.length() == 0)
    {
        return;  // nothing to match against
    }
    std::size_t pos = 0;
    while ((pos = subject.find(search, pos)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        subject.replace(pos, search.length(), replace);
        pos += replace.length();
    }
}
```

The error message is as follows:

```
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
? find(const char *, ?, ?)
? find(const stlpmtx_std::basic_string<char,stlpmtx_std::char_traits<char>,stlpmtx_std::allocator<char>> &, ?)
? find(const char *, ?)
? find(char, ?)
'
```

**Problem 1:-**

Is there a different way to use these functions in Eclipse? What should I do to make the error go away?

**Problem 2 :-**

What does the `?` sign mean in the error messages?

Comment: looks like a compiler misconfiguration: what compiler is eclipse invoking, and with which switches?

Comment: how do i find out ? i am very much new to eclipse c++ programing

Comment: There is no "eclipse c++ programming" thing: C++ is one thing, eclipse another. Give a look to the "project settings" of both VS and Eclipse and make shure they are both using the same C++ compiler and libraries.

Comment: What compiler are you using with Eclipse?  There is a `find` method that takes a string: [std::string::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find).